# What's the easiest/correct/safest way to upgrade from cakephp-2.0.2 to cakephp-2.0.3?

Tags: php, cakephp, upgrade, cakephp-2.0

The project was developed with cakephp-2.0.2.

Now i'm going to upgrade it to cakephp-2.0.3.

What's the easiest and safest way to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either:

Remove /cake in your 2.0.2 install and replace it the /cake directory of 2.0.3

or (preferable):

Install cake 2.0.3 to a new location

Copy 2.0.2 /app to the new installation. If you have any custom files in /plugins or /vendors they'll need to be moved too.

(Don't forget to empty the cache directories in /app/tmp/cache - leave the directories intact, just remove any files in them).

Comment: For a cake 2.0 project, you remove the lib/Cake folder.  It was moved from /cake to lib/Cake in 2.0.

Comment: @Richard, which method do you follow copying lib/Cake directory or copying app/ directory to the new cakephp-2.0.3 ? If i copy lib/Cake directory to the older one, this may not be completely upgraded to cakephp-2.0.3 because the folder structure of the new cakephp-2.0.3 can't be similar to older cakephp-2.0.0

Comment: Personally, I install a fresh CakePHP install and copy my app/vendors folders into it. My reasoning is that there's stuff outside of the cake directory (such as the root index.php file) that might have changed.

Answer (score 1):

whats the big deal?
simply replace the two core folders. run all tests and apply corrections where necessary.

Comment: What did you mean by two core folders ?